# Android shared Prefrence problem

Tags: android

HI all,

i want to ask can i save an array in shared prefrence(Default Shared Prefrence)...
if yes then pls help me to save the array in shared prefrence..
Any code would b great if available.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is an Array of Strings, then the workaround is quite strightforward - join the strings with a joiner that you know for sure does not occur in your array. The got string can be stored in the preferences. Then just split. If there is an Array of some other objects, then you need to generate string representation for each item and also join to one String to store in prefences.

Answer (score 3):

You could write each element of your array using a different key... something like this (for Strings):

```
void storeArrayToPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs, String a[]) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    for (int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++) {
        editor.putString("key" + i, a[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only get primitive data types from the SharedPreference class.  See this on the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html  `GetBoolean`, `GetInt`, etc.

Depending on what type of data you have,  you may want to consider using a SQLite database. [See here for a tutorial.](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

All the primitive data types like booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings are supported.

You can store all the values of the array in Key value format using a loop and later if you want to retrieve make use of HashMap.